# Shiny - Call panel from external code

Tags: r, shiny

I have been working on a Shiny application where the `ui.R` script has become long and becoming hard to manage. I would like to break up the code into different sections, and then call them within the `ui`. I would guess that this would be especially helpful with different panels that become nested and complicated.

Is there a way to do this?

Example `ui.R` script:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
))
```

It would be nice if I could change this into the following (I have written this in pseudo code):

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Iris k-means clustering'),

  source("call_sidebarPanel.R"),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot1')
  )
))
```

call_sidebarPanel.R

```
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', names(iris)),
    selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', names(iris),
                selected=names(iris)[[2]]),
    numericInput('clusters', 'Cluster count', 3,
                 min = 1, max = 9)
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I also do that in all my non-trivial apps. The trick is to use

```
source("file.R", local = TRUE)$value
```

[This shiny article](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html) has some information on this.

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks so much!